# JSONPath how to filter out objects that contains lists of empty objects?

Tags: json, jsonpath, jayway

I'm trying to use JSONPath (Jayway implementation), to get objects that contains a values array, that contains at least 1 non empty value. This is a simplified data I get from some service:

```json
[
  {
    "feature" : "city",
    "values" : [
      {
        "value" : "cba"
      },
      {},
      {
        "value" : "abc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "feature" : "country",
    "values" : [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

I've dozens of crazy approaches.

1. Get the objects with the value attribute

```json
$.[?(@..value)]
```

but this filters nothing I can still see both objects instead of only one.

2. I've also tried to filter by the length of the filtered `values` array but it doesn't work either, and returns an empty list:

```json
$.[?(@.values[?(@.value)].length()>1)]
```

I'm trying to work it out using online evaluator from [jsonpath.herokuapp.com](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)
I've been searching a lot and it seems that getting the length of the filtered array isn't possible, but the first approach looks like something that should work. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it work to ensure there is at least a first `value` element in `values`? Try: `$[*][?(@.values[0].value)]`

Comment: Works as well! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jayway-JSONPath you can use the empty [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)

**Filter the object**

```
$.[?(@..value empty false)]
```